# setInterval...requestAnimFrame...requestAnimationFrame..nothing works on Safari ARGH

Tags: javascript, safari, setinterval, requestanimationframe

So I have read hundreds of threads. I gave up on gifs because how they are poorly supported cross browser (the default min fps is 4-10 depending on the browser and there is no reset gif or play when loaded that works). SO I have decided to have some fun with an animated rig using javascript. I had noticed that Safari sucked in the fps on one thing I did before, but never thought much about is since I figured I did something wrong...

So I made this site using setIntervals, minimized the total number, clearIntervaled them using the var they were set to, and even tried not declaring them as global vars...i.e.

```
<script>
     var bob =setInterval("fps();",100);
     var going=0;

      fps(){
          if(going<10){
               ++going;
               document.getElementById('id').style.top=(1+going)+'px';
               document.getElementById("id").src="./elements/pic"+going+".png"; 
          } 

        else{
             clearInterval(bob);
        } 
</script>
```

That worked perfectly on IE, but safari decided that 100 = 1 sec?? I checked many sites and there were people complaining about it with no response or people talking that Safari and Chrome have better fps. So I redid the entire thing first reduing the total number of active setIntervals and then converted it over to...

```
 requestAnimFrame
```

And then to ...

```
requestAnimationFrame
```

but after all of that it still barely moves on Safari. I love how it runs on IE, and I figure the next step is to make a browser dependent variable that multiplies everything only is it is on safari...but I have a feeling that may not work either because perhaps it is just a memory issue, which sucks because as I understand it setInterval runs less often than requestAnimationFrame so it would seem a better choice.

I can put my code here, but it is a bit much and I figured that the specific code may be less important, but the page is [craibwoud.com](http://craibwoud.com/index). I have it on the setInterval version right now while I am tweaking the codes, but the supposed safari friendly version is [Craibwoud.com/safari](http://craibwoud.com/indexsaf).

Oh and I never got the

```
cancelAnimationFrame/cancelRequestAnimationFrame
```

to work, so I had to

```
if(value){function();}
```

them out using val=false if I needed to end them.

Sorry if my coding is a bit basic, but I am a bit new.

Edit: Here is a sample of one of the codes:

```
function bgfx(){
counter+=.1;

var trans=Math.round(counter); 

if (counter > 7){
    counter= 1;


}

document.getElementById("fx").src='./elements/bdfl'+trans+".png";

if(fxy_v){window.requestAnimationFrame(bgfx);}

else{document.getElementById('fx').src='./elements/bdoff.png';}
```

}

It is called using...

```
fxy_v=true;
fxy = bgfx();
```

Comment: Just installed newer OS on mac and it seems to be working (the setinterval version) excluding a glitch that seems to be related to setTimeout going faster than the requestAnimationFrame when a certain button is clicked. Also oddly enough the requestAnimationFrame version is working, but still is not going nearly as fast as it should.

Comment: Can anyone help? I have read most every post on requestanimationframe and nothing helps. I put my setinterval page back up as the main page because the request was much much worse.

Answer (score 0):

Safari implemented it as webkitRequestAnimationFrame originally. Check out this polyfill: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671

Also, make sure it works on your version of Safari: http://caniuse.com/requestanimationframe

Comment: Sadly I looked at that link many times before. I think he used window.requestAnimationFrame vs just requestAnimationFrame that others were using. I will try adding that back in and see if it helps. But one issue is all of the places talking about it are dealing with sprite or generated animation vs frame by frame or even just simply moving divs around.

Comment: Nothing in your answer helped. I even followed the links of the links at the base of the page I had not exhausted before.